# How to make a Jersey JAX-RS service a Spring bean itself

Tags: spring, web-services, jersey, jax-rs, spring-aop

I have a Jersey web-service class, say:

```
@Service
@Path("/serv")
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dao")
    Dao dao;


    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    public Response get(@QueryParam("hash") String hash) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now the auto-wiring works, because I use `jersey-spring3` as described here:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html

I also have the usual Servlet in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The beans are wired up, all cool.
The problem is that the service class itself doesn't seem to be managed by Spring itself.

So when I try to annotate the JAX-RS service , say with `@Timed` metrics annotation, the call is not intercepted by AOP.

Can I somehow overcome the issue? I'd like Spring to be able to "see" calls to service methods, say to `Service::get` in the above example.

Comment: `Service` **is** managed by Spring. The fact that `@Timed` is not working means that there is some misconfiguration. One possible cause would be that you don't have CGLIB on your classpath and therefore Spring cannot create proxies for the classes that don't implement an interface

Comment: @geoand but I did annotate the injected `Dao` with `@Timed` and that instance **is** interceped!

Comment: Does the `Dao` implement an interface?

Comment: @geoand of course not :-)

Comment: What kind of Spring configuration files do you have and where in which one does the timing configuration exist in?

Comment: @geoand Both `Service` and `Dao` are in one project, in sibling packages. Both packages are scanned by Spring. For metrics I use https://github.com/ryantenney/metrics-spring , so obviously I have dependency on spring aop and codahale metrics. I compared stacktraces and the call to `Service::get` does not come from any Proxy / Aspect. The calls to `Dao` do get proxied/intercepted.

Comment: Can you also post your Spring configuration and the web.xml you are using (if you are indeed using one)?

Comment: @geoand the web.xml is the above `<servlet>` and a url mapping. The as per spring config, the relevant line is `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>`, that's it. It's a simple, small project so far.

Comment: I can't really tell what's going on with the supplied info.

Comment: @geoand no problem, I myself suspect that the `ServletContainer` that gets the http requests is not in any way related to Spring, so when it delegates to `Service`, something different (than usual in Spring) happens..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java config you need to get the service classes from Spring to give to Jersey.  Something like:

```
public class JerseyProductConfig extends ResourceConfig {

@Inject
public JerseyProductConfig(ServletContext servletContext) {
    WebApplicationContext springFactory = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    register(springFactory.getBean(YourResource.class));
}
```

}

Note that I found this solution somewhere on stackoverflow but can't seem to find the post.